# were vs. are usage

Tags: tenses

Which of this is appropriate?

> When you were born, we were so happy because you **are** a boy.

Or

> When you were born, we were so happy because you **were** a boy.

I stumbled upon this on Facebook. And it kept me wondering.

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, this one is correct: When you were born, we were so happy because you **WERE** a boy.

But morally, neither of them.

You could say `We were so happy to have a baby boy`.

Comment: What is immoral about any of them?

Comment: Kris, maybe immoral is not the best word, but saying "we were happy because you were a boy" has some negative context, namely, it implies that if the baby were a girl the parents would be disappointed. That's what I meant.

Comment: I still fail to follow. Your rewording does not fix that. *Any* valid rewording won't fix that, and any rewording that fixes it won't be valid.